# Where can I find D&D Penny Arcade Podcast season 2 scenario?

Tags: dnd-4e, podcast

In the last episode of the D&D podcast season 2: (http://www.wizards.com/dnd/Article.aspx?x=dnd/4pod/20090408), Chris Perkins writes:

> for those wishing to follow in the footsteps of Acquisitions Inc. Look for the podcast scenario to appear in a future issue of Dungeon Magazine!

Which issue can I find this in and can I purchase just this issue? Are all of the podcast scenarios gathered in one place/publication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That podcast was compiled into a playable adventure and released as [Storm Tower](http://www.wizards.com/DnD/Article.aspx?x=dnd/duad/20090513) in Dungeon Magazine #166, with minor changes.

As it's a regular article on the D&D Insider site, you can download a PDF copy if you have a [D&D insider subscription](http://www.wizards.com/DnD/Subscription.aspx). A month of D&D Insider subscription costs $10, so you'll be able to download that and whatever else you want in the space of your month - it's yours, you paid for it.

You can also buy it as part of the Dungeon Magazine Annual volume 1. It's available [in print](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0786952458), which is perfect if you want a physical copy. [The volume is also sold in PDF format](http://www.dndclassics.com/product/110206/Dungeon-Magazine-Annual%2C-Vol.-1-%284e%29), though consider that this is more expensive than a DDI subscription, and the subscription already gives you access to the Dungeon Magazine archives.